# what is a builder‘s yard?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I learned the phrase *builder‘s yard* in a dictionary as an example. But what exactly does it mean? i.e. its function, purpose, etc.  I failed to find out any definition in Wikipedia, nor with Google. Could anyone tell its meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, but I would imagine this is a BrE phrase (or elsewhere in the Commonwealth) that is the equivalent of "lumberyard" in AmE.  It's a purveyor of building supplies.

Comment: As a BrE native: yes, correct. When I [google it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=wKu7WqSjFcfBgAbd3ZTYBw&q=builders+yard&oq=builders+yard&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0l9.32875.33024.0.33431.2.2.0.0.0.0.51.101.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.101....0.X0yunqq35dU) I get lots of hits for places to buy building materials. They mostly call themselves "builders merchants".

Comment: In case someone wondered, purveyor = supplier. It'd be nice to use more usual language in material for language learners.